# Repeated string concatenation

Tags: strings, comparative-review, prolog

I've been looking for a way to have a predicate that establishes that all elements of a list are substrings delimited by a given string. Analogues in other languages include: `'delimiter'.join(list)` in Python, `(mapconcat function sequence delimiter)` in Emacs Lisp, `array.join('delimiter')` in JavaScript, and I'm sure there are more of the kind. Below are three different variants I came up with, but I've a strong feeling that I'm reinventing the wheel here:

## join

```
join(_, [X], X) :- !.
join(Sep, [X | Xs], S) :-
    join(Sep, Xs, Sx),
    string_concat(Sep, Sx, Sy),
    string_concat(X, Sy, S).
```

Seems to be the simplest, but I don't like that it is not tail-recursive and that it has an obvious repetitive pattern.

## interleave

```
interleave([X], _, X) :- !.
interleave([X | Xs], Glue, Result) :-
    interleave(Xs, Glue, Previous),
    format(atom(Result), "~p~p~p", [X, Glue, Previous]).
```

Still not tail-recursive, no repetition, but I'm not sure how bad is `format` if compared to plain `string_concat`.

## mapconcat

```
reduce([], X, _, X) :- !.
reduce([X | Xs], Acc, Predicate, Result) :-
    call(Predicate, Acc, X, Interim), 
    reduce(Xs, Interim, Predicate, Result).
reduce([X | Xs], Predicate, Result) :- reduce(Xs, X, Predicate, Result).

mapconcat_helper(Glue, X, Y, Z) :- format(atom(Z), '~p~p~p', [X, Glue, Y]).

mapconcat(List, Glue, Result) :-
    reduce(List, mapconcat_helper(Glue), Result).
```

To my surprise, there isn't a `reduce`-like predicate in the standard library, so I had to write my own. Finally, this won't explode the stack for longer lists.

---

So, which one, if any of these is best? Perhaps there are libraries that already do this better? I'm using SWI Prolog, and am doing this mostly for self-education, so I'm not yet concerned with portability etc. If it's SWI-specific, I think it'd still do.

Comment: Check out `foldl/4`, for "reduce". The `!/0` you added only makes your version less general than what you can do with `foldl/4`.

Comment: Thanks @mat, Was `foldl` added after 6.0.2? Because I'm sure I searched for fold, but didn't find it. I think I added `!` due to instantiation mode of `string_concat`, but now I've checked and it works both ways, so... I don't know why I did it :)

Comment: 6.0.2 is quite outdated, I recommend you upgrade to 7.1.36 or later. Soon, 7.2 will be released as a stable release within the 7.x development branch. `foldl/4` is quite powerful and useful in many cases. Due to its completely relational nature, it can be used in more cases than may be apparent at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick browse through the [SWI-Prolog manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=manual) finds [`atomics_to_string/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomics_to_string/3):

> **atomics_to_string**(+*List*, +*Separator*, -*String*)
>
> Creates a string just like [`atomics_to_string/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomics_to_string/2), but inserts *Separator* between each pair of inputs. For example:
>
> ```
> ?- atomics_to_string([gnu, "gnat", 1], ', ', A).
> A = "gnu, gnat, 1"
> ```

Comment: It's funny, because I read that section of the manual, but didn't make a connection. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Also, worth noting. This predicate only exists in the development version 7.X.X and high, (stable versions 6.X.X don't have it).